# JavaFX implementing linked properties

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

What is the best way to implement linked or interdependent properties in JavaFX?

For example I have an interval which I'd like to represent by three integer properties, `lower`, `upper` and `range` such that `range = upper - lower` and if you try to set the range it also sets upper (to `lower + range`).

This is straightforward in traditional Java Beans (set/get methods) but JavaFX properties include the Observable concept and Bindings and it seems to get complicated quickly.

I've tried bindings but this makes the target property unsettable, also bidirectional bindings but I can only bind 'equality', not an expression.

I have started down the track of implementing `range` as a `javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty` but handling the listeners etc. seems to be a lot of work.

Is there a simpler way to do it?

*edit:*
This is what it would be using the JavaBean patterns:

```
private int lower = 0;
private int upper = 0;

public int getLower() {
    return lower;
}
public void setLower(int lower) {
    this.lower = lower;
}

public int getUpper() {
    return upper;
}
public void setUpper(int upper) {
    this.upper = upper;
}

public int getRange() {
    return upper - lower;
}
public void setRange(int range) {
    upper = lower + range;
}
```

How would I do this in the JavaFX way?
Here's what I tried

```
IntegerProperty lower = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "lower", 0);
IntegerProperty upper = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "upper", 0);
IntegerProperty range = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "range", 0);

public LinkedPropTest() { // Constructor
    lower.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        range.setValue(upper.getValue() - lower.getValue());
    });
    upper.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        range.setValue(upper.getValue() - lower.getValue());
    });
    range.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        upper.setValue(range.getValue() + lower.getValue());
    });
}
```

Which I think works but I must define a 'dummy' property and also (I think) adding ChangeListeners destroys any chance of using lazy evaluation.

Comment: So to get this correctly: You want all three properties to be standalone / settable?

Comment: Yes, so there are three properties that a user can bind to, but only two independent properties.

Comment: You answered both yes and no ;-)  Which ones are to be independent? You said two?

Comment: Yes. I added some code to the original post, hopefully that clarifies it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we need:

- Two default `IntegerProperty` objects as `SimpleIntegerProperty`
- and one custom `IntegerProperty` derived from [`IntegerPropertyBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerPropertyBase.html) to implement some special behavior for your needs.

So we have your properties as members:

```
private final IntegerProperty lower = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
private final IntegerProperty upper = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
private final IntegerProperty range = new IntegerPropertyBase() {

    {
        upper.addListener(obs -> update());
        lower.addListener(obs -> update());
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "range";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return Main.this;
    }

    private void update() {
        super.set(upper.get() - lower.get());
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int newValue) {
        upper.set(lower.get() + newValue);
    }

};
```

Our custom property is basically an observable composite number with the special case of being settable. So we have overwritten some methods and registered the necessary listeners.

And some example code to test / verify this:

```
private void printStats() {
    System.out.println("lower : " + lower.get() + " - upper: "
            + upper.get() + " - range: " + range.get());
    System.out.println();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    lower.addListener(obs -> {System.out.println("Lower changed"); printStats();});
    upper.addListener(obs -> {System.out.println("Upper changed"); printStats();});
    range.addListener(obs -> {System.out.println("Range changed"); printStats();});

    System.out.println(" ######### TEST #1 #############");
    lower.set(5);

    System.out.println(" ######### TEST #2 #############");
    upper.set(5);

    System.out.println(" ######### TEST #3 #############");
    range.set(10);
}
```

Comment: Great. I will also add that this works perfectly even when using the setValue(Number) method defined in WritableIntegerValue and when binding the variables further (it wasn't clear to me that it would without further overrides)

Comment: That is the advantage of (ab)using `IntegerPropertyBase` which is the base implementation doing most of the boilerplate stuff for managing dependencies and listeners.